# Replace a character in a text

Tags: r, regex

How do I replace the + with %2B:

Here is my code

```
x<-"asflj + ldjjsf ljsdlafj"
gsub("+","%2B",  x)
```

my output is:

```
"%2Ba%2Bs%2Bf%2Bl%2Bj%2B %2B+%2B %2Bl%2Bd%2Bj%2Bj%2Bs%2Bf%2B %2Bl%2Bj%2Bs%2Bd%2Bl%2Ba%2Bf%2Bj%2B"
```

and I want it to be `"asflj %20 ldjjsf ljsdlafj"`

Comment: you can escape the plus `"\\+"`

Comment: You can also do `gsub("[+]", "%2B", x)` to avoid escaping.

Comment: Do you want the output to have %20 or %2B?

Answer (score 3):

[`+` is a metacharacter](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) then you can set `fixed=TRUE` to skip it and get what you need.

```
> gsub("+","%2B",  x, fixed=TRUE)
[1] "asflj %2B ldjjsf ljsdlafj"
```

Or skip it by using `\\+`

```
> gsub("\\+","%2B",  x)
[1] "asflj %2B ldjjsf ljsdlafj"
```